# Quick Controls 2 bad looking

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquickcontrols2

Qt 5.10, Windows 10 desktop.

The following QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 250
    height: 100
    title: qsTr("My app")

    GridLayout
    {
        columns: 2

        Label {
            text: "Setting1:"
        }

        ComboBox {
            model: ["100%", "90%", "80%", "70%", "60%", "50%", "40%", "30%"]
        }

        CheckBox {
            id: tidle
            text: "Setting2:"
        }

        ComboBox {
            model: ["90%", "80%", "70%", "60%", "50%", "40%", "30%"]
            enabled: tidle.checked
        }
    }
}
```

gives the following result:

[image]

It looks quite badly for me:

1) "Setting1" label and checkbox are not visibly aligned.

2) Checkbox and ComboBox sizes are too big comparing to text size.

Do I miss something or it's the normal behavior?

Comment: In addition to the answer, the default style is focused more on being performant than pretty - try some of the other styles: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a normal behavior.

A [Control](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html) has the following layout:

[image]

For example `Label` has a padding of 0, on the other hand the `CheckBox` if it has it so that they are aligned there are 2 possible solutions:

- Set the leftPadding of CheckBox to 0:

---

```
CheckBox {
    id: tidle
    text: "Setting2:"
    leftPadding: 0
}
```

[image]

- Or set the Label to the same leftPadding of CheckBox:

---

```
Label {
    text: "Setting1:"
    leftPadding : tidle.leftPadding
}

...

CheckBox {
    id: tidle
    text: "Setting2:"
}
```

[image]

Qt offers the following guidelines to customize `Control`s:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html

For the case of the size of the `ComboBox` you could use [`FontMetrics`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontmetrics.html#font-prop) to calculate an appropriate size, in my case I'm in Linux and it was not necessary.

Comment: You're my hero! xD Btw, why don't make all controls' padding values equal to 0...

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev
Why do you say that? You probably do not see the effect because the ContenItem has an additional interior space.

Comment: No, your solution works fine for me. I meant Qt devs could make all padding set to 0 so one has not to set padding values as in your example...